# Regular expression anchored to beginning of any line containing the word "hello" in order they occur in string

Tags: regex, perl

Should find first `hello`, print character position... find next `hello` and print character positon... and the anchor can be any line that has the first `hello`...

Why doesn't it work?

Attempt #1:

```perl
$line = "\n hi\n   hiya \n   hello\n hi \n hello2";
$match = $line =~ m/^\s*(hello)/;
if (!$match) {
    die("not found\n");
}

print "found at pos: " . pos($line) . "\n";
$line = $';
$match = $line =~ m/^\s*(hello)/;
if (!$match) {
    die("not found\n");
}
print "found at pos: " . pos($line) . "\n";
```

Result: `not found`

Attempt #2:

```perl
$line = "\n hi\n   hiya \n   hello\n hi \n hello2";
$match = $line =~ m/\A\s*(hello)/;
if (!$match) {
    die("not found\n");
}

$line = $';
$match = $line =~ m/\A\s*(hello)/;
if (!$match) {
    die("not found\n");
}
print "found at pos: " . pos($line) . "\n";
```

Result: `not found`

Comment: You should always use `use strict; use warnings`, especially when learning and experimenting. Also, this question seems a bit academic. It is not often that you have input that contains newlines. This makes me think that you just made up some input to test with, that you think represents actual data, but doesn't actually. Depending on how you get your input, the answers you learn here could be fairly useless to your problem.

Comment: I have input that has newlines quite a bit. :) There are plenty of multiline formats out there are separated with something else. Indeed, I answered such a real world question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74466235/2766176

Answer (score 7):

For a "multiline" string need [`/m` modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#m) for `^` to match line beginnings inside the string

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $line = "\n hi\n   hiya \n   hello\n hi \n hello2";


while ( $line =~ /^\s*(hello)/mg ) { 
    say $1; 
    say pos $line 
}
```

Prints

```
hello
22
hello
34
```